# Does $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}[x]$ have unique factorisation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Let $p$ be a prime greater than $2$.

Does $$\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}\right)[x]$$ have
unique factorisation ?

Of course this is valid if one considers

$$\left(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\right)[x]$$

instead.

Comment: Is it even a domain?

Comment: quite right-i will change it to a unique factorisation ring.

Comment: What is a unique factorisation ring, if not a domain?

Comment: not sure why this is important, have counterexamples in mind ?

Comment: Can this count as a non-unique factorization: $p=p(p+1)=p(px+1)=p(px^2+1)=\cdots$? (This shows why we need an integral domain.)

Comment: @user26857: It's not clear since a definition of unique factorization hasn't been proposed, but that might not be a counterexample because all of those factorizations only differ by units (e.g. the inverse of $px + 1$ is $1 - px$). Although that example is definitely a counter-example to other expectations one might have had.